# Hashicorp Vault error "groups," claim not found in token

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I am trying to configure OIDC login with Azure AD in Hashicorp Vault, but I get this error:

```
"groups," claim not found in token
```

Its happen just when I try to apply one policy using groups. Using default group (reader group) it works

This is all steps that I did:

**Policy configuration:**

`vault policy write manager manager.hcl`

Content of manager.hcl:

```
path "/secret/*" {
    capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list"]
}
```

`vault policy write reader reader.hcl`

Content of reader.hcl:

```
path "/secret/*" {
    capabilities = ["read", "list"]
}
```

**Activate OIDC:**

`vault auth enable oidc`

```
vault write auth/oidc/config \
        oidc_discovery_url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{my-tenant-id}/v2.0" \
        oidc_client_id="{my-client-id}" \
        oidc_client_secret="{my-client-secret}" \
        default_role="reader"
```

```
vault write auth/oidc/role/reader \
        bound_audiences="{my-client-id}" \
        allowed_redirect_uris="https://{my-site}/ui/vault/auth/oidc/oidc/callback" \
        allowed_redirect_uris="http://localhost:8250/oidc/callback" \
        user_claim="email" \
        policies="reader" \
        verbose_oidc_logging="true"
```

And then to login `vault login -method=oidc`

With above commands I can login.

The problem comes when I change roles to match OIDC groups (following this doc https://learn.hashicorp.com/vault/identity-access-management/oidc-auth#cli-command-3):

```
vault write auth/oidc/role/manager \
        bound_audiences="{my-client-id}" \
        allowed_redirect_uris="https://{my-site}/ui/vault/auth/oidc/oidc/callback" \
        allowed_redirect_uris="http://localhost:8250/oidc/callback" \
        user_claim="email" \
        groups_claim="groups", \
        policies="manager" \
        verbose_oidc_logging="true" \
        oidc_scopes="https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
```

```
vault write identity/group name="manager" type="external" \
        policies="manager" \
        metadata=responsibility="Manager"
```

```
vault write identity/group-alias name="{my-group-hash-1}" \
        mount_accessor={id-of-oidc-config} \
        canonical_id="{group-id-from-above-command}"
```

And then when I try to login got the error  `"groups," claim not found in token`
When I put the token in jwt.io debugger, there is a list of groups like this:

```
  "groups": [
    "my-group-hash-1",
    "my-group-hash-2",
    ...
  ],
```

How can I fix this to define polices based on groups from token?
Vault version is 1.4.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this command:

```sh
vault write auth/oidc/role/manager \
        bound_audiences="{my-client-id}" \
        allowed_redirect_uris="https://{my-site}/ui/vault/auth/oidc/oidc/callback" \
        allowed_redirect_uris="http://localhost:8250/oidc/callback" \
        user_claim="email" \
        groups_claim="groups", \   # <----- You have a comma here
        policies="manager" \
        verbose_oidc_logging="true" \
        oidc_scopes="https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
```

you have a bonus comma on the `groups_claim` argument. Remove the comma and it should sort out your problem.

Comment: Thanks! I reviewed it several times and didn't see the comma there